# A cross-browser way of iterating over sets. JS

Tags: javascript, set

I have a basic set:

```js
var set = new Set([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]);
```

I want to iterate over it:

```js
for (var el of set) {
  console.log(el)
}
```

BUT: a `for...of` loop is not supported in all browsers. How can I iterate over a Set *without* a `for...of` loop?

Comment: Consider using babel to "transpile" the code before you put it live.

Comment: If the browser doesn't support `for..of`, it almost certainly doesn't support Sets either. They're both ES2015. Transpiling would result in `Symbol.iterator` references, which means you'd also need a `Symbol.iterator` polyfill as well

Comment: You should define the range of browsers you want to support. It will be slightly impossible to support in fact all browsers. And to polyfill for of, just use a regular for loop and iterate the "old" way over your collection

Comment: @SirOneOfMany I don't think you can use an ordinary `for` loop for a Set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to bother everyone, I found an 'answer' to it myself. This is for anyone who came across this question and wants an answer.

Anyway, the only reason one would use sets is to make sure that an element doesn't appear more than once. The solution is to do this manually, and keep it as an array.

```js
var arr = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]; // The array that would've gone to the Set
var newArr = [], l = arr.length;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  if (newArr.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1) newArr.push(arr[i])
}
console.log(newArr) // [0, 1]

// Then you can iterate over the newArr as much as you want:
for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
  console.log(newArr[i]) // 0 and then 1
}

// Console
/*
[
  0,
  1
]
----------
0
----------
1
*/
```